# How to minimize the method call to only once if you are finding different words in the same file

Tags: java

I am using below code to find specific word in the file.I am calling same method twice to find different words from the same file.
Can we minimize this call to only once and find the two words at one go?

```
int expiredCount = countWord("-Active-", fileEntry.toPath());
int pendingCount = countWord("-Cancelled-", fileEntry.toPath());

public static int countWord(String stringToLookFor, Path path) {
    int count = 0;

    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(path + "");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            int startIndex = strLine.indexOf(stringToLookFor);
            while (startIndex != -1) {
                count++;
                startIndex = strLine.indexOf(stringToLookFor,
                        startIndex + stringToLookFor.length());
            }
        }
        in.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("countWord Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you definitely can. How complex it ends up being depends on what you need. Do you need individual counts for each one?

Comment: You can even count all words in a single pass (for instance, building a `HashMap<String, Integer>`), and then simply look up any word you want counted in the resulting map. In text without lots of unique identifiers, this approach is not much more expensive than your current code.

Comment: I need individual counts for each one

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Map<String, Integer> countWord(Set<String> words, Path path) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (String word : words)
        map.put(word, 0);

    Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).forEach(line -> {
        for (String word : words) {
            int pos = 0;
            
            // you can use another logic to find all required words in the givecn line
            while (true) {
                pos = line.indexOf(word, pos + 1);

                if (pos == -1)
                    break;

                map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1);
                pos += word.length() =;
            }
        }
    });

    return map;
}
```